# How to calculate the size of an object in memory using Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, memory-size

How to calculate the size of an object in memory using Silverlight?

Comment: you want to calculate size of your custom objects??

Comment: check out this.
http://blog.headup.com/tag/silverlight/

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing the custom object should be serializable to be able to calculate its size at runtime.
2. Serialize and get the length of the array that is the size of the object, 
   excellent write up and example code - http://whydoidoit.com/2010/04/08/silverlight-serialization/